# JavaScript browser close event (nob tabs)

Tags: javascript, events, browser

I know that `onbeforeunload` and `unload` events are triggered while a user closes the browser tab or the browser itself, so my question is:

**Is there any way to detect only browser close (not tabs), like you completely destroy your browser process?**

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: The only way way I know to achieve what I think you want is to open the tab with window.open() -- then when you close the whole browser, onbeforeunload() will still kick in with Leave/Stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my research on this subject, I found out that as of **October 2017**, there is **no way** to handle full browser close event in JavaScript.